# React Showing Fetched Data in Option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use a api to get country list for that I am using fetch , after getting the list I need to show the country list as option in UI , currently m able to get it print it to console but on option it os not reflecting  kindly check what I am doing wrong & how to fix ,

```js
const [contry, setcontry] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
  const urlp = "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries";
  fetch(urlp)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong on api server!');
      }
    })
    .then(data => {
      // console.log(data.countries)
      const lp = data.countries
      //   console.log(lp);
      setcontry(lp)




    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}, [])
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
    <option>Global</option>
    <option>Global1</option>

    {contry.map((x) => { console.log(x.name);
    <option value={x.name}>{x.name}</option>



    })}
```

Comment: You're not `return`ing the <option> from the `.map()` callback

Comment: omg didn't notice thanks was going to pull out my hair over this

Comment: This is a common mistake. When troubleshooting the `console.log()` gets added to test the content. Not realizing this breaks the implicit `return`. Whenever you add another statement to a arrow function always add the `return` keyword too.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your code is that you are not returning anything from the `contry.map` function.

So, by changing your code

from

```js
{contry.map((x) => { console.log(x.name);
    <option value={x.name}>{x.name}</option>
})}
```

to

```js
{contry.map((x) => { 
   console.log(x.name);
   return <option key={x.name} value={x.name}>{x.name}</option>
})}
```

will work.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [contry, setcontry] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    const urlp = "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries";
    fetch(urlp)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Something went wrong on api server!');
        }
      })
      .then(data => {
        // console.log(data.countries)
        const lp = data.countries
        //   console.log(lp);
        setcontry(lp);
      }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, [])


  return (
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option>Global</option>
        <option>Global1</option>
        {contry.map((x) => { 
          console.log(x.name);
          return <option key={x.name} value={x.name}>{x.name}</option>
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```